# Find unknown matrix in equation with 3 multiplications.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

A matrix $D$ is calculated as $A*B*C$.

I need to find the matrix $B$ given matrices $A$, $C$ and $D$.

After some trial and error it seems that the following equation is needed to reproduce matrix $B$ whilst retaining the correct order of transformations:

$B=A^{-1}*D*C^{-1}$

Why does this work?

Comment: Are $A$ and $C$ invertible?

Comment: @Seth All of the matrices are invertible, yes.

Comment: Then just left multiply by $A^{-1}$ and then right multiply by $C^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remembering that matrix multiplication is not commutative, that if $A=B$ then $AC=BC$ (it is not the case that if $A=B$, then $AC=CB$), and that $A*A^{-1}=I$, we can do the following:
$$A*B*C=D\\A*B*C*C^{-1}=D*C^{-1}\\A*B=D*C^{-1}\\A^{-1}*A*B=A^{-1}*D*C^{-1}\\B=A^{-1}*D*C^{-1}$$
Remember that this only works if matrices $A$ and $C$ are invertible.

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic explanation, this makes it much clearer for me and now I realize what is happening :)